# MySQL Innodb: Large Composite PK no other indexes

Tags: mysql, primary-key, innodb, composite-index

I am creating an Innodb table with four columns.

Table

```
 column_a (tiny_int)
 column_b (medium_int)
 column_c (timestamp)
 column_d (medium_int)

 Primary Key -> column_a, column_b, column_c
```

From a logical standpoint, columns A, B, C must be made into a PK together.However, to increase performance and be able to read directly from the index (using index) I am considering a PK that comprises of all 4 columns (A, B, C, D).

QUESTION

What would the performance be of appending an additional column to the Primary Key on an Innodb table?

CONSIDERATIONS

- Surrogate primary keys are absolutely out of the question
- No other indexes will exist on this table
- Table is read/write intensive (both about equal)

Thank you!

Comment: Adding `column_d` to your PK will mean that one can end up with multiple records with identical values in `(column_a, column_b, column_c)` so long as `column_d` differs.  Also, why resist adding other indexes to the table: if you want a covering index, why not add one *in addition to* the PK?  Remember, **premature optimization is the root of all evil** - are you actually faced with a performance problem that you're trying to solve?  If so, what is it?

Comment: Very good point with `column_d` and I asked wondering if there was a rule of thumb or some guiding principle. There are quite a few tables with large PKs and I was hoping for guidance. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In InnoDB, the `PRIMARY KEY` index structure includes all non-key fields and will automatically use them for covering index queries and row elimination. There is no separate "data" structure other than the `PRIMARY KEY` index structure. It is not necessary to add additional fields to the `PRIMARY KEY` definition itself. Note that it won't show `Using index` when it's using the `PRIMARY KEY` on an InnoDB table, because it's a different code path which doesn't trigger the addition of that message.

Answer (score 0):

A few things to consider:

1. Unless the query in question uses all of the columns in the index, the index will not be used.
2. As jeremycole notes: in the Innodb structure all row data is stored in the B-tree leaf nodes of the clustered index (PRIMARY INDEX)

This concept is covered:
http://www.innodb.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/innodb-file-formats-and-source-code-structure.pdf
http://blog.johnjosephbachir.org/2006/10/22/everything-you-need-to-know-about-designing-mysql-innodb-primary-keys/

... and in jeremy's blog post here:
http://blog.jcole.us/2013/01/07/the-physical-structure-of-innodb-index-pages/

As such, a query on A, B, C will be sufficient for efficiently obtaining all values on this Innodb table.

Comment: I'm sorry, but this answer is just incorrect. The `PRIMARY KEY` index structure in InnoDB includes all non-key fields as its "value", meaning that there is no separate "data" structure (as is the case with e.g. MyISAM `.MYD` files). Creating a separate covering index for this case will do more harm than good.

Comment: jeremy is absolutely correct, about my earlier incorrect answer.